# Regex: Matching a string starting with anything, then a hyphen

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume I have the following text:

BBC - Here is the text

How would I use regex to test if the string starts with `"* - "` ?

Then remove the `"* - "`, to be left with just `"Here is the text"`. (I am using python).

I use `"*"` because it obviously won't start with `"BBC - "` every time, it might be some other substring.

Would this work?

```
"^.* - "
```

Thank you very much.

Answer:

```
m = re.search(ur'^(.*? [-\xe2\u2014] )?(.*)', text)
```

This worked. Thank you @xanatos !

Comment: Have you tried it? IF so either it works or tell us what is wrong

Comment: I mentioned I am using Python, thanks!

Comment: More information is required. If the string doesn't start with - and the text contains - any regex solution will think the text started with - when it didn't and thus return only part of the text.

Comment: @Akinakes How can I make sure that the occurrence is only replaced in the string if the string starts with that pattern? I'm pretty sure python has .startswith() but it doesn't accept regex.

Comment: I haven't used Python in years, but shouldn't this be achievable with string functions alone? Return everything after the first occurrence of " - ".

Comment: @Yoni201 You either have to know the possible prefixes or their length or you can't have - in the text. Just consider this string: "prefix <missing char> lost text - text you can get". There's no way of knowing that the lost text is part of the text and not the prefix. Of course my objection is invalid if you always have a prefix and it ends with -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
str = u"BBC \xe2 abc - Here is the text"
m = re.search(ur'^(.*? [-\xe2] )?(.*)', str, re.UNICODE)

# or equivalent
# m = re.match(ur'(.*? [-\xe2] )?(.*)', str, re.UNICODE)

# You don't really need re.UNICODE, but if you want to use unicode
# characters, it's better you conside à to be a letter :-) , so re.UNICODE

# group(1) contains the part before the hypen
if m.group(1) is not None:
    print m.group(1)

# group(2) contains the part after the hypen or all the string 
# if there is no hypen
print m.group(2)
```

Explanation of the regexes:

```
^ is the beginning of the string (the match method always use the beginning
  of the string)
(...) creates a capturing group (something that will go in group(...)
(...)? is an optional group
[-\xe2] one character between - and \xe2 (you can put any number of characters
        in the [], like [abc] means a or b or c
.*? [-\xe2] (there is a space after the ]) any character followed by a space, an hypen and a space
      the *? means that the * is "lazy" so it will try to catch only the
      minimum number possible of characters, so ABC - DEF - GHI
      .* - would catch ABC - DEF -, while .* - will catch ABC - 

so

(.* [-\xe2] )? the string could start with any character followed by an hypen
         if yes, put it in group(1), if no group(1) will be None
(.*) and it will be followed by any character. You dont need the 
     $ (that is the end-of the string, opposite of ^) because * will 
     always eat all the characters it can eat (it's an eager operator)
```

Comment: How about `NBC - Some Artist - Some Album`. Shouldn't it split after the first hyphen? Maybe using reluctant instead of greedy would be wiser.

Comment: How would I allow for any number of whitespaces before and after the hyphen? Your code doesn't work with: "LOS ANGELES — text"

It might have to do with non-ascii characters? Using the longer "hyphen" above gives an error: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'

Comment: @Yoni201 There are something like three or four hypens in UNICODE... Tell me which ones you want (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen , under In computing)

Comment: Would it be possible to check for all of them?

Comment: @Yoni201 Yes, but I don't remember the syntax for unicode regexes in python. In general you do `[-\xe2]` but then you have to turn on the unicode mode of regex by using `re.UNICODE` as the last parameter.

Comment: It still isn't working for me. Here is my text:
"LOS ANGELES — Text". http://www.pythonregex.com/ isn't getting any groups either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34784/discussion-between-yoni201-and-xanatos)

Comment: @xanatos there is an issue. It works for: "BBC - Hello there", but if my text is something like "Here is my dog, her name is Betsy - A great name". the hyphen will be treated the same. I know in terms of Regex there is nothing that can be done, but how would I remove text before the hyphen only if it consists of only 1 or 2 words? Thanks!

Comment: @Yoni201 The concept of "word" is quite complex to explain to a regex parser (together with the concept of word-boundary). Perhaps it's better you simply replace `.*?` with `.{1,10}?` (or another number) that will limit the first word to n letters.

Comment: @xanatos How would i check for something like "LOS ANGELES -- Text", where there are two hyphens instead of one. Would I need a separate regex to check for two, then one, because of the "lazy" nature of the first regex?

Comment: @Yoni201 The rules are becoming a little fuzzy, don't you think? Instead of `[-\xe2]` you put `[-\xe2]{1,2}`

Comment: I'm actually looking at different news articles and what they contain. Thank you!

Comment: @Yoni201 No space before the `{`, and `\xe2` isn't an hypen, it's `â`

Answer (score 3):

Here's 'match everything before the first hyphen and that hyphen itself' pattern:

```
/^[^-]*-\s*/
```

It reads as follows:

```
^      - starting from the beginning of the string...
[^-]*  - match any number (including zero) of non-hyphens, then...
-      - match hyphen itself, then...
\s*    - match any number (including zero) of whitespace
```

Then you can just replace the string matched by the pattern with empty string: the resulf of the replacement is probably what you need overall. )

Answer (score 0):

Use the `?`-operator:

```
'^(.+ [-] )?(.+)$'
```

Maybe you want to implement it with a little more flexibility towards the whitespaces...

Some trivial and crude test script (using php instead of python, sorry for that!):

```
<?php
$string  = "BBC - This is the text.";
$pattern = '/^(.+ [-] )?(.+)$/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens);
?>
```

Output of the test scipt:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(23) "BBC - This is the text."
  [1] =>
  string(6) "BBC - "
  [2] =>
  string(17) "This is the text."
}
```

The first parentheses match any text at the beginning of the string which starts with any character of length>0 whch is followed by a space character, then a literal hyphen and another space character. This sequense may or may not be present. The second parentheses match all the rest of the string up to the end.

Comment: Could you please explain how this matches any substring and then the hyphen? I'd like to learn how it works, thanks!

Comment: The `?` in `.*?` makes `*` *non-greedy*, meaning it will stop matching as soon as it can, not as later as it can (the default greedy behaviour).

Comment: OP is using python, but really, the regex is just what matters :)

Comment: @Haidro Sorry, missed that detail, thanks. But indeed the regex is what matters.

Answer (score 0):

`/^.+-/` should work.

Following are the test cases according to your requirement:

Passes: `foo -`

Passes: `bar-`

Passes: `-baz-`

Passes: `*qux-`

Passes: `-------------`

Fails: `****`

Fails: `-foobar`